# WebStorm is highlighting basic JavaScript syntax as being incorrect in a nodejs file

Tags: node.js, webstorm

WebStorm is highlighting my server setup file as having syntax errors that definitely aren't. This is a nodeJs file...

Is there something I can do to help WebStorm to understand better?

Here is a screen shot of what I'm seeing:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your JavaScript language version in `Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript`. Be sure it's set to ECMAScript 6, since you are using ES2015 syntax.

[image]

Comment: I thought it was something simple. Thanks!